# Program not recognizing conditional statements in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I'm trying to print "None" if the input entered by the user is not found in a text file I created. It should also print if the lines if word(s) **are** found in the text file.

My problem right now is that it is not doing both conditionals. If I were to remove the "line not in user_pass" it would not print anything. I just want the user to be able to know if the strings entered by the user can found in the file and will print that line or "none" if it is not found.

I commented out the ones where I tried fixing my code, but no use.

My code below:

```
def text_search(text):
try:
    filename = "words.txt"
    with open(filename) as search:
        print('\nWord(s) found in file: ')
        for line in search:        
            line = line.rstrip() 
            if 4 > len(line):
                continue
            if line.lower() in text.lower():
                print("\n" + line)
            # elif line not in text: # the function above will not work if this conditional commented out
            #     print("None")
            #     break

            # if line not in text:  # None will be printed so many times and line.lower in text.lower() conditional will not work
            #   print("none")

except OSError:
    print("ERROR: Cannot open file.")

text_search("information")
```

Comment: You do realize that `continue` tells it to skip the rest of the loop right?

Comment: @Reedinationer that conditional with 'continue' just makes sure to recognize words over 4 characters. This is like finding words in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change `for line in search:` to `for line in search.readlines():` I don't think you're ever reading from the file... Have you tried to just `print(line)` and ensure your program is reading anything at all?

**@EDIT**

Here is how I would approach the problem:

```
def text_search(text):
    word_found = False
    filename = "words.txt"
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            file_by_line = file.readlines() # returns a list
    except OSError:
        print("ERROR: Cannot open file.")
    print(file_by_line) # lets you know you read the data correctly
    for line in file_by_line:        
        line = line.rstrip() 
        if 4 > len(line):
            continue
        if line.lower() in text.lower():
            word_found = True
            print("\n" + line)
    if word_found is False:
        print("Could not find that word in the file")

text_search("information")
```

I like this approach because

1. It is clear where you are reading the file and assigning it to a variable
2. This variable is then printed, which is useful for debugging
3. Less stuff is in a `try:` clause (I like to not hide my errors, but that's not a huge deal here because you did a good job specifying `OSError` however, what if an `OSError` occured during `line = line.rstrip()` for some reason...you would never know!!)
   If this helped I'd appreciate if you would click that green check :)

Comment: I get this when I put that line. "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"

Comment: @smokingpenguin I'll edit my post to show a more conventional way of opening files.

Comment: `for line in search` is fine.  For large files it's even necessary, reading a multi-GB file into a list isn't practical.

Comment: @Reedinationer That is a better clear method. Now if I were to search a word that is not on the file, how can I make the output print "not in file"? That is like my main concern because it would repeatedly either print "not in file" if the text is not in the file. But if the word IS in the file I want that word to print, which your code does already.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, I agree and that's why my initial answer was just to actually **read** the file. However, being that I can't reproduce the error OP commented (it's not a mcve after all...) I figured it would be better to give a solution that I know would work because in all the books I read to teach Python to myself all of them used that method to open files. I did assume he was dealing with a small file though, so if you would like to provide your solution for dealing with large files and it's different than my initial post, be my guest!

Comment: @smokingpenguin I've updated the script. Again, it'd be awesome if you could click that green check mark if this helped

Comment: @Reedinationer YOU'RE AWESOME. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
def find_words_in_line(words,line):
    for word in words:
        if(word in line):
            return True;
    return False;

def text_search(text,case_insensitive=True):
    words = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),text.split()));
    if(case_insensitive):
        text = text.lower();
    try:
        filename = 'words.txt'
        with open(filename) as search:
            found = False;
            for line in search:
                line = line.strip();
                if(find_words_in_line(words,line)):
                    print(line);
                    found = True;
            if(not found):
                print(None);
    except:
        print('File not found');

text_search('information');
```

Didn't really understand your code, so making one on my own according to your requirement.